# Fatal error: Class 'My_Ibanner_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, css, magento, fatal-error, magento-1.9.1

I installed ibanner module from magentoconnect extension and that was not working so I deleted all the files and folder relatively to that module and now is displaying this error, plzz help me:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'My_Ibanner_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547
```

Comment: You need to remove the class from that file, please show us the code of Mage.php

Comment: Do you have a file named as Data.php under Helper folder of My_Ibanner module, you may be missing the Helper declaration in the config.xml